# I can't run a c# project in VS 2022 because i have Attach on the run button

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, runtime-error, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to build and run a project in Visual Studio Community 2022 but I can't because of this:

[image]

As you can see in the image i have the run button disable. Can anyone help me?

I don't realy try anything because I see no solutions on internet.

Comment: Do you actually have a solution open? If I open VS without opening a solution then I see that *Attach* button, which enables you to debug a running process. If I open a solution, that button changes to *Start*. What is shown in your *Solution Explorer*?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the startup project to the project that you want to run?  If the startup project somehow gets set to a library, then it cannot run.  The currently selected  startup project is shown with a **bold** font.

To change the startup project, mouse over the project, right click and select "set startup project"